# AHK script: pressing CapsLock to toggle CapsLock + Suspend

Tags: toggle, autohotkey, suspend, capslock

### Setting up an Autohotkey script.

How to make CapsLock key do 'Suspend' while toggling the CapsLock state on the same key press?

I want this:

```
CapsLock::
Suspend
ToggleCapslock()
Return
```

The code should be able to make CapsLock key toggle both the CapsState and the Suspend state with a single key press of CapsLock.

---

How to achieve that?

The script below doesn't toggle both the CapsLock state and the Suspend state.

1st key press: it activates Suspend and sets CapsLockState to OFF.

2nd key press: it does unsuspend, CapsLockState remains at OFF.

```
CapsLock::
Suspend
;ToggleCapslock()
if GetKeyState("CapsLock", "P")
    SetCapsLockState, Off
if !GetKeyState("CapsLock", "P")
    SetCapsLockState, On
return

ToggleCapslock() {
    flag := false
        if (flag) {
            SetCapsLockState, On
        } else {
            SetCapsLockState, Off
        }
        flag := !flag
}
```

I want to toggle Suspend/Unsuspend AND CapsLockState ON/OFF on each single press of CapsLock.

(Essentially, this thread asks how to put actions to CapsLock key while maintaining its native function.)

Glad for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Final easy Solution:**

```
~CapsLock::Suspend
```

The documentation covers the most fundamental solution for this problem you could possible come up with. (Found by reading through the documentation: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols)

> ~ :  When the hotkey fires, its key's native function will not be blocked (hidden from  the system).

**< closeThread** **>**

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the Pause key? Or suspend as in suspending the hotkey macro?

Try:

```
CapsLock::
    Send {Pause}
    ToggleCapslock()
Return
```

There is good help here on Pause:

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#other

**Pause**   Pause or Ctrl+NumLock. While Ctrl is held down, Pause produces the key code of CtrlBreak and NumLock produces Pause, so use ^CtrlBreak in hotkeys instead of ^Pause.

Suspending the hotkeys is here:
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Suspend.htm

**Suspend**  Disables or enables all or selected hotkeys and hotstrings.

Let us know what you want,

Comment: I want to put Suspend as in suspending the hotkey macro on the CapsLock key while CapsLock still has it's native function of toggling CapsLockState.

'CapsLock::Suspend' makes CapsLock loose it's native function. That's the issue.